# Rode VideoMic upgrade

Tags: microphone, upgrade

I currently have a Rode VideoMic and am looking to upgrade. I am currently looking at the Rode NTG-2 as I can plug it directly into my DSLR as it can power itself. However, after seeing reviews it seems that it is not much different audio quality wise from my VideoMic. I have around £250 to spend on audio so any recommendations would be good (looking specifically for a shotgun but lapel would do). Is the NTG-2 a good step up as nearly all people start off with VideoMic when starting audio but where do you go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my video mic more suitable as the ntg 2. the ntg 2 has less output and is more noisy. Uf you want to upgrade buy the ntg3 and a seperate mixer/recorder an sync afterwards with plural eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to up your game audio quality wise, you need to move in to dedicated recorders, or at least a pre-amp or mixer that you feed in to the camera.  This will allow you to use real, good quality professional microphones and greatly improve your sound quality over having to work around the constraints of the mic jack on your DSLR.

Personally, I use a Zoom H4n and record directly to that, but there are also people who take the line output from there and feed it in to the camera's input after going through the necessary pads.